# How to properly start and stop ReplyingKafkaTemplate

Tags: spring-kafka

I'm using ReplyingKafkaTemplate to make synchronous call with reply. From what i found till now, every time i'm going to use template i call start() and after receiving response the stop() method. However, I came across a problem with the message commit, the offset of my consumer was not increasing. I assumed, that is because consumer did not have time to make a commit, because basic commit time (property "auto.commit.interval.ms") is set to 5 seconds in ConsumerConfig class and I'm stopping him immediatelly after receiving a message. So i changed this time to 1 ms, to commit immediatelly after receiving message. This way it's working, but i would like to understand it better

My question is : How start() and stop() methods should be used properly, is there a purpose to start it before every call and stop after ? And what is a right way to make sure that commit was made ?

Btw. I would be honored if Gary answered the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not start and stop the container each time; just leave the reply container running all the time.

In any case, you should leave `enable.auto.commit` alone - while it's default is `true`, Spring will set it to `false` unless you explicitly set it to `true`.

The container will commit the offset in a more deterministic manner than the built-in auto commit mechanism.